# Accelerating Universe and dark energy or photon absorption or neergy decay?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, dark-energy

I’m an RF/microwave engineer with physics background, and had a question regarding dark energy and experimental observations. 
FYI I don’t qualify as a professional physicist, hence asking a professional opinion to see if this has already been considered and disproved. 
Perhaps some brilliant minds here can answer this.

In my understanding, people have tried explaining accelerating universe as dark energy (lambda), which is the currently favored view, or tried modified theories of gravity which don’t fit all of experimental data. I’m wondering whether anyone tried applying exponential loss of intensity with distance (Rayleigh scattering), I’m guessing the exponential loss model would have to be combined with free space loss, since both scattering and 1/R^2 apply simultenously. Additionally “just for fun” one could try exponential decay in photon energy with distance to see if this would fit the data. I don’t have any physical intuition of how the decay in photon energy would occur (without dark energy).

Examples in RF/microwave engineering:
In optical fiber cables there is an exponential decay in signal power with fiber cable length due to mostly Rayleigh scattering. This is easy to explain – the number of photons scattered is directly proportional to number of photons interacting with fiber scattering centers evenly distributed along the length of the fiber, which sets up an exponential decay dependence vs length. The wavelength for a pure delta function frequency would not change. Similar exponential vs distance loss exists in RF cables due to thermal loss. Many engineers not familiar with this effect are shocked to discover that free space propagation (1/R^2) beats “low loss” cables at long distances, because exponentials always win at long distances. However if you look at short distances – it is “obvious” that free space is orders of magnitude more lossy than RF cables, so it is counterintuitive that a cable is more lossy over long distances.

Neither of the above two fiber or coaxial transmission medium examples change photon energy or frequency, just the number of photons measured.

Hence I’m wondering whether either:
1)  Type 1a supernova distance calculation (or any other intensity measurement) has an exponentially growing error (per current models) with distance due to exponential decay of intensity with distance, due to Rayleigh scattering above. After all, space isn’t empty, there is diffuse matter present in it of all sizes. If there is an exponential error in intensity (and hence distance) it may look like the universe is accelerating, whereas the reality is that we’re underestimating the path loss (exponentially with distance).

2)  Somehow the photon energy has an exponential decay with distance. E.g. photon energy coming out of space medium of length L, somehow loses frequency or Energy that is proportional to incoming energy. I don’t have any physically intuitive ideas for this effect, but just wondering if this was tried “for fun” to see if fits.

Thank you so much, 
Pavel